# Maven not in the allowed range

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, m2eclipse

I created a Scala project in Eclipse Luna. When I try to run it I get the below exception :

```
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
Detected Maven Version: 3.3.3 is not in the allowed range 3.3.9.
```

I tried to add enforce plugin but I got the same error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please show the full logoutput and not only excerpts.

Answer (score 0):

If your "range" is 3.3.9, you shoud probably deactivate the enforcer plugin. This should allow you to use a different version of Maven.